# Point on a archimedean spiral given distance from a known point.

Tags: polar-coordinates

I have an archimedean spiral, and know these points:

angle and distance from center of the beginning of the spiral,
angle and distance from center of the end of the spiral

I would need the angle and distance from center of a point that is X mm in distance along the line from the start...

all values are in mm.

for example (angle, distance to center):

P start: 2Pi , 20

P end: 6Pi, 60

Distance from P(start) to px: 110mm

[image]

how can this be caluclated? In my case semplicity is more important than precision, it is enough to have a approximation.

Comment: How are you representing the points for which you want the angle and distance? In polar coordinates, input is the angle of point and the output is the distance from the origin. I'm asking because if you know this, you shouldn't ask about the angle between and that's what made me unsure

Comment: @AryanHemmati sorry, I am not a matematician, and my knowledge is almost zero.. so i hope i understood your question: what I need is the position of Px, relative to the origin.. angle and distance from the center. The only thing I know about this point is the distance in mm (along the spiral) from Pstart. Please let me know if i misunderstood your question. thanks for your time.

Comment: so you basically are on Pstart, walk along the line for 110 mm then stop. I would need to know your distance from 0/0 and the angle from the origin so in above example it would be somewhere around 36/3,6 Pi

Comment: Alright now how you're going to define the point p-start

Comment: @AryanHemmati like in the post above. in this example 2 Pi/20. angle from start, and distance from center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This spiral has equation
$$r=10 \frac{t}{\pi}$$
Length of the spiral is
$$L(x)=\int_0^x\sqrt{r^2+{r'}^2}\,dt$$
In this case we must have
$$L(x)=\int_{2\pi}^x \frac{10 \sqrt{t^2+1}}{\pi } \, dt=110$$
which means
$$\frac{5 x \sqrt{x^2+1}}{\pi }+\frac{5 \log \left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)}{\pi }-10 \sqrt{1+4 \pi ^2}-\frac{5 \log \left(\sqrt{1+4 \pi ^2}+2 \pi \right)}{\pi }=110$$
approximated
$$x\approx 10.4\sim 360°+235.7°$$
Distance from origin is given by the spiral equation
$$r=10 \frac{10.4}{\pi}\approx 33.1$$

---

$$...$$
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why is your X up there? shouldnt it be somewhere in the lower part around 3,6 Pi/36? the distance (110) is not from the origin, but from Pstart

Comment: @sharkyenergy OK, I missed that particular. I'll edit ASAP

Comment: also, whats the distance from the center of X?

Comment: grazie.. :) no rush at all..

Comment: thank you very much! Now I will try to understand this, and understand how its calcualted. ( ihave no mathematical background and at the moment its greek for me, but Ill find out!) thank you very much for your time and help! buon proseguimento!

Comment: stupid question.. I need to implement this into a program. Would it be possible to convert this into a formula, where I have 5 values as input (angle start, radius start, angle end, radius end, distance from start) and I get the angle X? so without knowing the function of the spiral?

Comment: @sharkyenergy No, I don't think it is possible. The equation to solve is based on the integral which is based on the polar equation of the spiral

Comment: given that I am ok with an approximation, how would this work out in your opinion? I know how much R increases on each rotation. (in my example 20) calculate spiral length for 1 2 and 3 full cycles and get the formula for the increase of distance/turn. with that I could calculate how many turns my "distance" is and get the angle. the angle can then be inserted in the formula of my spyral to get the radius.. would that work?