# Determining length of curve with polar coordinates with constant slope

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

First question on Mathematics. Please be gentle!

I have two sets of polar coordinates. A curve connects them with the radius changing at a constant rate from $radius_0$ to $radius_1$.

I need to determine:

- Coordinates for the point on the curve $L$ distance away from the starting point. ($L=0.1$ in my situation)
- (Optionally) The length of the entire curve

I know that, generally, the length is determined with this equation:

$$ ds = \sqrt{r^2 + \left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2} d\theta . $$

My problem is that I'm programming a microcontroller (a very tiny processor) that can't integrate. I can solve by hand for individual coordinates, but I get stuck when trying to generalize it.

Thanks, in advance, for any help you can offer here.

[Here's a visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e48SO.gif) of a curve described by the two coordinates $(0, 0)$ and $(4\pi, 4\pi)$, where coordinates represent $(r,\theta)$. In this example, the slope is $1$ (i.e. the radius is always equal to the radians). In my specific situation, I'm guaranteed that the radius is always between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: If I'm interpreting the description of "a curve connects them with the radius changing at a constant rate from radius0 to radius1", you are describing an [Archimedian spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral). On the wikipedia page, there is [a section on arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral#Arc_length,_curvature), which might be what you want.

Comment: The Archimedian spiral is indeed an example of such a curve, but in that example, the slope is always 1 (i.e. the radius and radians increase at the same rate). I may have two coordinates like (0, 0radians) and (1, 3.14radians) where the radius increased at 1/3.14 the rate of the radians. (Edit: I might also have two points with the same radius, which would just be an arc segment.)

Comment: Scratch that -- you're absolutely right. Slope is a part of the equation (angular velocity A). I need to then offset the starting theta so that it aligns to the starting radius. I also need to offset the ending theta so that the angular spread between start and end doesn't change. Then the equation from wikipedia will apply (with exceptions for when the angular distance is zero or the slope is 0). This effectively solves my second question (length of the curve). I need to play around with it to see if I can use it to solve my first question (coordinates on the curve for dist=0.1).

Comment: Reversing the equation to determine angular distance given a total length is not trivial :(.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an easy way of doing it. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016044/point-on-a-archimedean-spiral-given-distance-from-a-known-point) is about a similar question, and the answer can only be determined numerically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we consider the case of the Archimedian spiral, what you want is to inverse the equation
$$L=\frac{a}{2}\left[\theta\,\sqrt{1+\theta^2}+\log \left(\theta+\sqrt{1+\theta^2} \right)\right]$$

Let $k=\frac {2L}a$ and consider that we look for the zero of
$$f(\theta)=\theta\,\sqrt{1+\theta^2}+\log \left(\theta+\sqrt{1+\theta^2} \right)-k$$
For sure, this will require a nmerical method and the problem is to find a reasonable starting point.

If we assume that $k$ is large, we can expand the function as series
$$f(\theta)=\theta^2+\left(\log (2 \theta)+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{8
   \theta^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{\theta^4}\right)-k$$

So, a very first approximation would be
$\theta_0=\sqrt k$.

A much better one
$$\theta^2+\left(\log (2 \theta)+\frac{1}{2}\right)=k \implies \theta_1=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} W\left(\frac{1}{2} e^{2 k-1}\right)}$$ where $W(.)$ is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

For example, using $k=1234$, this would give $\theta_0=35.1283$ and $\theta_1=35.0607$ while the "exact" solution is $\theta=35.0607$ (!!).

If you need to polish the root, use Newton method and the iterates will be
$$\theta_{n+1}=\frac{\theta_n\,\sqrt{1+\theta_n^2}-\log \left(\theta_n+\sqrt{1+\theta_n^2} \right)+k } {2\sqrt{1+\theta_n^2} }$$
Starting with the simplest estimate $\theta_0$, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \theta_n \\
 0 & 35.12833614 \\
 1 & 35.06072218 \\
 2 & 35.06065703 \\
 3 & 35.06065703
\end{array}
\right)$$

The second case would correspond to small values of $k$. Doing the same
$$f(\theta)=2\theta+\frac{1}{3}\theta^3+O\left(t^5\right)-k$$

So, a very simple estimate would be $\theta_0=\frac k 2$. You could make it better solving the cubic equation
$$\theta_1=2 \sqrt{2} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 k}{4   \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$

Using $k=12.34$, , this would give $\theta_0=6.17$ and $\theta_1=2.74032$ while the "exact" solution is $\theta=3.15976$.

**Edit**

If you consider the case of the general Archimedian spiral
$$r=a+b \theta^{\frac 1c}$$ you cannot integrate except if $a=0$. If this is the case, you will face a nightmare since
$$L=b t^{\frac{1}{c}} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2 c};1+\frac{1}{2 c};-c^2   t^2\right)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergoemetric function and there is no hope for any approximation.

Comment: It seems sqrt(k) works reasonably well for large angular distances while k/2 works well for small angular distances. The problem I'm seeing is that neither works well if the starting radius is not zero (i.e., the starting theta is not zero degrees). For instance, traveling from (0.9dist,90rad) to (1.0dist, 100rad) gives me very bad values when solving for L=0.1. Actual L is resulting in very high values (4.1 or 9.5).